# How to connect MySQL to VB6 Data Environment at design time?

Tags: mysql, vb6, odbc

Is there a way to connect MySQL to VB6 at **design time**?

I know the option of setting up a DSN on Windows but wouldn't this make the application dependent on the machine where it was built?

Is it technically possible to make such a connection at design time so that I can create my data reports easily?

Thanks!

Comment: "I know the option of setting up a DSN on Windows but wouldn't this make the application dependent on the machine where it was built?" No, just create a DSN on the target machine. Or use a DSNless connection string everywhere.

Comment: +1 for the idea - I never thought of it like that. Your method would mean that the target machine would need the same DSN but I guess it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: It's a DSN that specifies how to connect to a data source. That is exactly what they're designed for.

Comment: Actually DSNs are strongly deprecated for a number of reasons. They were replaced by the UDL a long, long time ago. However those are mainly for use with OLEDB Providers. Yet nothing says a UDL can't use the thunking Provider for ODBC you always use (implicitly or explicitly) when you connect from ADO to a creaky ODBC Driver.

Comment: A useful link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274536

Comment: This sounds more like a report issue?  With ActiveReports (for example) you specify the connection info at design time and can change it programatically at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible a great utility is created by MySql people but that is know by very less developers as after they rapidly transferred to .Net Program and the utility is [VBMySQLDirect](http://www.vbmysql.com/), Very good utility to run in Connect VB6 real time as in other programs

Comment: How come you say this is from the MySQL people? There's nothing I could find on their site. This is a third-party developer and I don't know if it's compatible with VB6. Have YOU tried this with real-world projects?

Comment: Yes, I am using it and easily can embed in the software. Again it is confirmed that it is from MySQL peoples